# How to iterate over two dataloaders simultaneously using pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, zip, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to implement a Siamese network that takes in two images. I load these images and create two separate dataloaders.

In my loop I want to go through both dataloaders simultaneously so that I can train the network on both images.

```
for i, data in enumerate(zip(dataloaders1, dataloaders2)):

    # get the inputs
    inputs1 = data[0][0].cuda(async=True);
    labels1 = data[0][1].cuda(async=True);

    inputs2 = data[1][0].cuda(async=True);
    labels2 = data[1][1].cuda(async=True);

    labels1 = labels1.view(batchSize,1)
    labels2 = labels2.view(batchSize,1)

    # zero the parameter gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # forward + backward + optimize
    outputs1 = alexnet(inputs1)
    outputs2 = alexnet(inputs2)
```

The return value of the dataloader is a tuple. 
However, when I try to use `zip` to iterate over them, I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
Exception NameError: "global name 'FileNotFoundError' is not defined" in <bound method _DataLoaderIter.__del__ of <torch.utils.data.dataloader._DataLoaderIter object at 0x7f2d3c00c190>> ignored
```

Shouldn't zip work on all iterable items? But it seems like here I can't use it on dataloaders.

Is there any other way to pursue this? Or am I approaching the implementation of a Siamese network incorrectly?

Comment: Instead of making two dataloaders , i think it would be much easier if you just return two images from a single dataloder.

Comment: since a dataloader divides the images into batches, would I simply have a batchsize of 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you are struggling to make a right dataloder function. I would do:

```
class Siamese(Dataset):


    def __init__(self, transform=None):
    
       #init data here
    
    def __len__(self):
        return   #length of the data

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        #get images and labels here 
        #returned images must be tensor
        #labels should be int 
        return img1, img2 , label1, label2
```

Comment: since this class's __getitem__member gets called with argument idx, with two images would it need to get called with two indices? (self,idx1,idx2)? or would I simply just return two random images? For example,                           img1 = os.path.join(self.root_dir,imgNames[idx])
img2 = os.path.join(self.root_dir,imgNames[idx + 1]) ?

Comment: I guess you have equal number of same images  ( in two arrays).. so using one index you could load the images from two arrays of images. ... or you could make another array of just indices of same images and load those images using idx of __getitem__ of dataloader

Answer (score 17):

Further to what it is already mentioned, `cycle()` and `zip()` **might create a memory leakage problem** -  especially when using image datasets! To solve that, instead of iterating like this:

```
dataloaders1 = DataLoader(DummyDataset(0, 100), batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
dataloaders2 = DataLoader(DummyDataset(0, 200), batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
num_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    for i, (data1, data2) in enumerate(zip(cycle(dataloaders1), dataloaders2)):
        
        do_cool_things()
```

you could use:

```
dataloaders1 = DataLoader(DummyDataset(0, 100), batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
dataloaders2 = DataLoader(DummyDataset(0, 200), batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
num_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    dataloader_iterator = iter(dataloaders1)
    
    for i, data1 in enumerate(dataloaders2)):

        try:
            data2 = next(dataloader_iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            dataloader_iterator = iter(dataloaders1)
            data2 = next(dataloader_iterator)

        do_cool_things()
```

Bear in mind that if you use labels as well, you should replace in this example `data1` with `(inputs1,targets1)` and `data2` with `inputs2,targets2`, as @Sajad Norouzi said.

KUDOS to this one: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1917#issuecomment-433698337

Comment: Great answer for when you need different batch sizes from each dataset

Comment: @afroditi if i am using image and labels from first dataloader and mask and labels from second dataloader, how ca i procees them?

Comment: @nour It would be hard to do that during the training process using shuffle=True option. You can pre-process the data accordingly to create a dataloader giving (image, label, mask) simultaneously, given that the labels are used for mapping. Else if labels from dataset 1 are different from dataset 2 you could do create again a single dataloader providing batches of (image, mask,label1,label 2).

Answer (score 16):

If you want to iterate over two datasets simultaneously, there is no need to define your own dataset class just use TensorDataset like below:

```
dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(dataset1, dataset2)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)
for index, (xb1, xb2) in enumerate(dataloader):
    ....
```

If you want the labels or iterating over more than two datasets just feed them as an argument to the TensorDataset after dataset2.

Comment: Thanks, it is the most relevant and easy-to-go answer

Answer (score 9):

To complete @ManojAcharya's answer:

The error you are getting comes neither from `zip()` nor `DataLoader()` directly. Python is trying to tell you that it couldn't find one of the data files you are asking for (c.f. `FileNotFoundError` in the exception trace), probably in your `Dataset`.

Find below a working example using `DataLoader` and `zip` together. Note that if you want to shuffle your data, it becomes difficult to keep the correspondences between the 2 datasets. This justifies @ManojAcharya's solution.

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

class DummyDataset(Dataset):
    """
    Dataset of numbers in [a,b] inclusive
    """

    def __init__(self, a=0, b=100):
        super(DummyDataset, self).__init__()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __len__(self):
        return self.b - self.a + 1

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return index, "label_{}".format(index)

dataloaders1 = DataLoader(DummyDataset(0, 9), batch_size=2, shuffle=True)
dataloaders2 = DataLoader(DummyDataset(0, 9), batch_size=2, shuffle=True)

for i, data in enumerate(zip(dataloaders1, dataloaders2)):
    print(data)
# ([tensor([ 4,  7]), ('label_4', 'label_7')], [tensor([ 8,  5]), ('label_8', 'label_5')])
# ([tensor([ 1,  9]), ('label_1', 'label_9')], [tensor([ 6,  9]), ('label_6', 'label_9')])
# ([tensor([ 6,  5]), ('label_6', 'label_5')], [tensor([ 0,  4]), ('label_0', 'label_4')])
# ([tensor([ 8,  2]), ('label_8', 'label_2')], [tensor([ 2,  7]), ('label_2', 'label_7')])
# ([tensor([ 0,  3]), ('label_0', 'label_3')], [tensor([ 3,  1]), ('label_3', 'label_1')])
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I think using zip would be very inefficient in many cases.
Some datasets have huge number of images which are loaded at runtime. Zip will iterate over entire dataset causing it to load images as once.

Answer (score 5):

Adding on @Aldream's solution for the case when we have varying length of the dataset and if we want to pass through them all at same epoch then we could use the `cycle()` from `itertools`, a Python Standard library. Using the code snippet of @Aldrem, the updated code will look like:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from itertools import cycle

class DummyDataset(Dataset):
    """
    Dataset of numbers in [a,b] inclusive
    """

    def __init__(self, a=0, b=100):
        super(DummyDataset, self).__init__()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __len__(self):
        return self.b - self.a + 1

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return index

dataloaders1 = DataLoader(DummyDataset(0, 100), batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
dataloaders2 = DataLoader(DummyDataset(0, 200), batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
num_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, data in enumerate(zip(cycle(dataloaders1), dataloaders2)):
        print(data)
```

With only `zip()` the iterator will be exhausted when the length is equal to that of the smallest dataset (here 100). But with the use of `cycle()`, we will repeat the smallest dataset again unless our iterator looks at all the samples from the largest dataset (here 200).

P.S. One can always argue this approach may not be required to achieve convergence as long as one does samples randomly but with this approach, the evaluation might be easier.

Comment: I am using the same approach but then how do you calculate dataset length for dataloaders1 to calculate loss? Thanks!