# Memory error when iterate over two dataloaders simultaneously in pytorch

Tags: out-of-memory, pytorch, dataloader

I am trying to train my model using 2 dataloaders from 2 different datasets.

I found how to set up this by using `cycle() and zip()` because my datasets are not the same length from here: [How to iterate over two dataloaders simultaneously using pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444059/how-to-iterate-over-two-dataloaders-simultaneously-using-pytorch)

```
  File "/home/Desktop/example/train.py", line 229, in train_2
    for i, (x1, x2) in enumerate(zip(cycle(train_loader_1), train_loader_2)):
  File "/home/.conda/envs/3dcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 346, in __next__
    data = self.dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/.conda/envs/3dcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/home/.conda/envs/3dcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 80, in default_collate
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/home/.conda/envs/3dcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 80, in <listcomp>
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/home/.conda/envs/3dcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 56, in default_collate
    return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at CPUAllocator.cpp:64] . DefaultCPUAllocator: can't allocate memory: you tried to allocate 154140672 bytes. Error code 12 (Cannot allocate memory)
```

I tried to solve that by setting `num_workers=0`, decreasing the batch size, using `pinned_memory=False` and `shuffle=False`...
But none of it worked... I am having 256GB of RAM and 4 NVIDIA TESLA V100 GPUs.

I tried to run it just by not training in 2 dataloaders simultaneously but individually and it worked. However for my project I need this parallel training with 2 datasets...

Comment: You must accidentally call something that materializes all your data in the memory. Can you share a code snippet?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I found the solution to this one: cycle() ans zip() might create memory leakage problems. This solves it: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1917#issuecomment-433698337

Comment: Then, post an answer to your question, so other people can find it more easily ;-) And, you'll get a bronze batch for it as well.

Comment: Did so, thanks again for trying to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1917#issuecomment-433698337) discussion, instead of `cycle()` and `zip()` I avoid any errors by using:

```
  try:
     data, target = next(dataloader_iterator)
  except StopIteration:
     dataloader_iterator = iter(dataloader)
     data, target = next(dataloader_iterator)
```

kudos to @srossi93 from this pytorch post!